# Scale a circle on hover maintaining the width of the border

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a circle without background, only border, and I want it to scale on hover:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"  />
    <style>
    #circle{
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 20% auto;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    #circle:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: scale(6);
        border: 1px solid black;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="circle">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u36nfxs0/2/

The problem, as you can see, is that the width of the border scales as well. Is there any way to scale the circle maintaining the width of its border?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use transform, adjust intead the dimensions (width, height, and explicit margins:

```css
#circle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20% auto 0 auto;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

#circle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  margin-top: calc(20% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
</div>
```